# 'IEnumerator': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me solve this compile error. I get the error **'IEnumerator': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'** I searched it up and found try and foreach, But when I test it crashes my compiler, So I assume this is incorrect.

```
    public static int ReadAddress(string Process_Name, string Address_Offsets)
    {
        Process[] processesByName;
        if ((processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process_Name)).Length == 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        int num = -1;
        while (Address_Offsets.Contains("  "))
        {
            Address_Offsets = Address_Offsets.Replace("  ", " ");
        }
        int startIndex;
        while ((startIndex = Address_Offsets.IndexOf("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1)
        {
            Address_Offsets = Address_Offsets.Replace(Address_Offsets.Substring(startIndex, 2), "");
        }
        string[] array = Address_Offsets.Split(new char[]
        {
            ' '
        });
        if (array[0].Contains("+"))
        {
            string[] array2 = array[0].Split(new char[]
            {
                '+'
            });

            using (IEnumerator enumerator = processesByName[0].Modules.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    object obj = enumerator.Current;
                    ProcessModule processModule = (ProcessModule)obj;
                    if (processModule.ModuleName.ToLower() == array2[0].ToLower())
                    {
                        num = processModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32() + int.Parse(array2[1], NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    }
                }
                goto IL_11C;            
        }
        num = int.Parse(array[0], NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        IL_11C:
        if (array.Length == 1)
        {
            return num;
        }
        byte[] array3 = new byte[4];
        keeProc.ReadProcessMemory(processesByName[0].Handle, num, array3, 4, 0);
        num = BitConverter.ToInt32(array3, 0);
        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int num2 = int.Parse(array[i], NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            keeProc.ReadProcessMemory(processesByName[0].Handle, num + num2, array3, 4, 0);
            num = ((i != array.Length - 1) ? BitConverter.ToInt32(array3, 0) : (num += num2));
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you verify and complete the code, please? Some things are missing and brakets mismatch. What is the line of the error?

Comment: A little baffled by this question, since the code example doesn't even contain a `using` statement. Are you sure the error is even coming from this code?

Comment: The error states you are using a `using` statement. Yet, no `using` is the code you post. Please verify the line where the error is referring to in your IDE, and post a snippet of that portion. This portion of the code appears to be unrelated to the error.

Comment: forgot to include that I tryed to fix it here is the original code for the first line
 using (IEnumerator enumerator = processesByName[0].Modules.GetEnumerator())

Comment: using (IEnumerator enumerator = processesByName[0].Modules.GetEnumerator())
    {
     while (enumerator.MoveNext())
     {
      object obj = enumerator.Current;
      ProcessModule processModule = (ProcessModule)obj;
      if (processModule.ModuleName.ToLower() == array2[0].ToLower())
      {
       num = processModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32() + int.Parse(array2[1], NumberStyles.HexNumber);
      }
     }
     goto IL_11C;

Comment: First you should update the question, not post code in the comments.  Second  `IEnumerator` does not inherit from `IDisposable` so it cannot be used in a `using`.  What makes you think that the enumerator would be disposable in the first place?  Why don't you just use a `foreach` instead?  Finally why are you using a `goto`, those should be avoided?

Comment: When I did that, I got this error(Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'IEnumerator' because 'IEnumerator' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator)
Im new to c# and need help
 foreach (IEnumerator enumerator in processesByName[0].Modules.GetEnumerator())

Comment: Just a little question: what is `processesByName`? Again: can you verify and complete the code *in the question*, please? Some things are missing and brakets mismatch *(there is no using)*. What is the line of the error? **And why a goto?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
using (IEnumerator enumerator = something.GetEnumerator())
```

then `IEnumerator` would have to inherit `IDisposable`.

However, it doesn't, so the compiler complains.

There is, however, a second possibility that you will have to rewrite the code to handle. The types involved doesn't state that they inherit/implement `IDisposable`, but the *actual object* is of a type that does. The compiler is unable to verify this and thus won't compile but you can force it yourself with this change:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = processesByName[0].Modules.GetEnumerator();
using (enumerator as IDisposable)
{
    ... your code here
}
```

This will check if the object instance is of a type that implements `IDisposable`, and thus dispose it. If it isn't, `as IDisposable` will return `null` and `using` will not do anything. It won't throw a `NullReferenceException` either so that's actually safe to do.